# Test to check if a list is present inside a python list of lists

Tags: python

Basically, I need to get few permutations of a list. So, the method that I have used is to shuffle the list string randomly to get the permutation and add it to a list, while adding I check if there exists the same permutation in the list. I am not able to implement the check. Here is the code that I have written.

```
list = [x for x in range(0,max)]
totalperm = 10
perms = []
while(len(perms) <> totalperm):
    random.shuffle(list)        
    if list not in perms:
        perms.append(list)
```

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because you're working with a reference to the single list the whole time, so it is always in the list after the first time you append it.

Consider:

```
perms = []
items = [1, 2, 3]
random.shuffle(mylist)   # perhaps items is now [2, 1, 3]
perms.append(items)      # perms is now [[2, 1, 3]]
random.shuffle(mylist)   # perhaps items is now [1, 3, 2]
perms.append(items)      # now what is perms?
```

The answer is, `perms` has two references to a single list, so it is [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]].

In your code, `items` and `perms[0]` are the same object and have the same value. So when you ask if `items` is in `perms` the answer is always yes. Because you just put it in there!

The solution is simple: add a copy of the list.

```
perms.append(items[:])
```

By the way, you should probably use a `set` rather than a `list` for storing your permutations. It's much faster to check membership of a `set` and attempts to add duplicates are simply ignored. The only downside is that you can't put lists in a `set` because lists are mutable and therefore unhashable -- fortunately, you can just convert them to tuples, which are immutable and hashable. Then you have:

```
items = range(0, max)    # Python 3: items = list(range(0, max))
perms = set()
nump  = 10
while len(perms) < nump:
    random.shuffle(items)
    perms.add(tuple(items))
```

Comment: You can't add lists to sets because they are unhashable (and mutable). Use `tuple(items)` instead of `items[:]`.

Comment: Rob: Yep, can't believe I forgot that. Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Use python's builtin `set` to prevent duplicates:

```
perms = set()
while len(perms) != totalperm:
    random.shuffle(lst)        
    perms.add(tuple(lst))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're shuffling the list, you're modifying it in place. Later, you add *a reference to it* to your list of perms. Next time through your loop, you shuffle the list in place again. If you look at perms, it will contain n references to your original list.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
shuffled = list[:]
random.shuffle(shuffled)
if shuffled not in perms:
    perms.append(shuffled)
```

Comment: Even, I thought the same as you did. So, I did the following :      ' perms = []
  while(len(perms) <> totalperm):
        listnew = list            
        random.shuffle(listnew)        
        if listnew not in perms:
            perms.append(listnew)            
            print perms
        del listnew '   But this doesn't work either.

Comment: listnew = list won't work, you'd need listnew = list[:] to explicitly copy the list

Comment: @AnandGupta, `listnew = list` does not create a copy of a list, it just creates a new variable pointing to the *same* list. You need `listnew = list[:]`. I would check out the `set` examples, which are much more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

`[1,2,3] in [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] == True`

Works for me. Is this all of your code?

Comment: If you store the list in a variable and then check, then this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going into an infinite loop because you change `list` in place.  Then you test to see if it is in `perms`, big surprise, it is!  So it can never append `perms`.

Repeat ad nauseum.

Here's how I did it:

```
import random
max = 4

list = [x for x in range(0, max)]

totalperm = 10
perms = []
while(len(perms) < totalperm):
    copiedlist = list[:]
    random.shuffle(copiedlist)     
    if copiedlist not in perms:
        perms.append(copiedlist)
        print perms
    else:
        print "It's already there, egads!"
```